# How to find PS (paragraph separator character) in file?

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I oppened an XML file in VSCode.

VSCode warned me that there are unusual line terminators, like [paragraph separator](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2029).

[image]

Using utilities bundled with git bash for windows, or python, how can I find all paragraph separator characters in a file ?

Comment: what happens if you press the `Remove .....` button

Comment: @rioV8 I guess it removes the characters listed in the popup. But the file is so big it makes no difference to my human eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work in bash, where unicode can be printed like `$'\u2029'`:

```
sed $'s/\u2029/HERE(&)/g' file.xml
```

- `&` is replaced with the paragraph separator. In a terminal it will probably just look like `HERE()`.
- Or maybe use `sed $'s/\u2029/HERE/g'` in case it messes up the terminal.
- `grep $'\u2029'` will list lines containing them.

There's also

```
hd file.xml | grep --color=always 'e2 80 a9'
```

You can delete them permanently with:

```
sed -i $'s/\u2029//g' file.xml
```